# Getting NullPointerException when trying to stream().filter().collect(Collectors.toList())) on Java list

Tags: java, list, lambda, nullpointerexception, ebean

I got a problem while trying to search a specific Java object in a list. 
Actually i got the search function i want working for another Java class. Now i tried it for a different one but instead of returning a list of results i get a NullPointerException.

This is how my function looks:

```
 public static List<Customer> searchByEverything(String keyword){
    List<Customer> customerList = find.all(); //Using java Ebean

    System.out.println(keyword); //Check if keyword is not empty
    System.out.println(customerList); //Check if list is not empty

    Predicate<Customer> customerPredicate = u -> u.name.toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase());

    try{
        return customerList.stream().filter(customerPredicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the strack trace from Exception e:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at models.Customer.lambda$searchByEverything$2(Customer.java:174)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:891)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at models.Customer.searchByEverything(Customer.java:179)
at controllers.Application.searchCustomers(Application.java:262)
at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$17$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Routes.scala:479)
at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$17$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Routes.scala:479)
at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:157)
at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:156)
at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:136)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:73)
at play.http.HttpRequestHandler$1.call(HttpRequestHandler.java:54)
at play.mvc.Security$AuthenticatedAction.call(Security.java:53)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:108)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:108)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:56)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:48)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492)
at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:108)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:112)
at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:111)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:110)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:110)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Action.scala:103)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

As i said, i have exactly the same search implemented for a different class and it works perfectly fine. Both `customerList` and `keyword` are not empty. The only difference between searching in my `customerList` and the other list, is that it has around 4500 objects with around 50 attributes per object. Maybe that's the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: While this question will 100% get closed as duplicate of "What is a NPE" question, could you post this line: `at models.Customer.lambda$searchByEverything$2(Customer.java:174)` (so line 174)

Comment: Maybe there are some users whose `name` attribute is null

Comment: Just a side-note, you can also use `parallelStream` (might improve performance https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams/2785/parallel-stream#t=201607281158351104612)

Comment: @nbokmans that's the lambda itself. The lambda's code is part of the question.

Comment: Sorry if this is a duplicate... i'm really overstrained with this problem. 
@nbokmans 
As f1sh says, this line is the definition of the lambda expression.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Very likely `u.name` is `null`

Try to change your `Predicate` in

```
Predicate<Customer> customerPredicate = u -> (u.name != null && u.name.toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase()));
```

To see what's the Customer instance that has `name == null`, you could add a `peek` method in your chain.

```
customerList.stream()
.peek(c -> { 
   if (c.name == null) {
      // do something...
   }
}).filter(customerPredicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: While i'm not getting a NullPointerException anymore, it returns all of the objects now. You are probably right that u.name is null, but i can't figure out why?

Comment: @EliasJohannes I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this did the job. probably really was that there were null references in the DB.